# javascript: scoping with let vs none

Tags: javascript

I have a forEach loop and a for loop nested inside of it.  Why is that outside of the for loop , but still inside the forEach loop, I have `word = foo`.  Then that value of `word` can be logged outside of the entire forEach loop however, when I make it `let word = "foo"` , the console log statement fails and says `word is not defined`?

```
function mainFunction() {
    array.forEach(function (element, index) {
       for (var key in list) {
         //do something
       }
       word = "foo"
    }

    console.log(word)
}
```

Comment: add `"use strict;"` as first statement of the `forEach` callback and you will get the proper error. You are creating a global variable, it's some oddity that is allowed in non-strict mode.

Comment: Maybe be a bit gentler with the downvotes for beginners, people.  Give folks a chance to learn before you blow 'em away.  The hard thing about learning is you haven't learned enough to know how to frame your questions.

Comment: @JDB and jmealy , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Let satement

> The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

```js
function test(){
  let x = 1;

  if(x === 1) {
    let x = 2;
    console.log(x);// output: 2
  }
  console.log(x); //output: 1
}

test();

console.log(x); // Uncaught ReferenceError
```

## No statement

Variables should be declared with `let`, `const`, or `var`. 
Omitting them is widely considered a mistake, because the **variable ends in the global scope**, generating *global scope pollution*, and difficulty to trace or debug.

It may also incur in variables overriding ( bugs, unexpected behavior...)

> If your code runs in `"strict mode"` (or inside a module), an error will be triggered.

```js
function test(){
  x = 1; // becomes window.x

  if(x === 1) {
    let x = 2;
    console.log(x);// output: 2
  }
  console.log(x); //output: 1
}

test();

console.log(x); // output: 1
console.log(window.x); // output: 1
```

---

## Solution to your problem

You should declare the variable at the top of your function.

```js
function mainFunction(array) {
    let word; // declare 'word' here
    array.forEach(function (element, index) {
       word = "foo";
    })
    console.log(word)
}

mainFunction([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't use `let`, `var` or `const` to define your variable, then JavaScript implicitly adds your `word` variable to the global object.

Basically, this:

```
word = "foo"
```

Is the same as this:

```
window.word = "foo"
```

This is widely considered to be bad practice and is generally indicative of a mistake. This is why most linters [will mark this as an error](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef).

Comment: it's additionally an error in strict mode (as noted on a comment on the question), which any sane person uses for writing bigger projects (imho). More specifically, step 5 of [PutValue](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-putvalue) just has some awkward extra case for non-strict.

Comment: @ASDFGerte - 100% agree, but adding `"use strict";` to an existing project usually requires some careful planning and a big commitment. If you're going to take that step, you may as well make everything an ES6 module, in which case the `"use strict";` is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two scopes in javascript: Global and local. [The only thing that can create a scope is the function keyword](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/#function-scope).

Variables are fetched by first looking into the local scope and if not found are then searched in the parent scope above the chain until found. If not found and `use strict` mode is not set, they are `auto` created for you in the global scope.

With that said you can see that what would happen is that the variable `word` would simply not be found in the scope of `forEach`. In this case JS does what many people do not want it to do and the reason why many people use `use strict` mode ... it would add it for you in the global scope since it was not able to located in anywhere in the scope chain.

This causes many issues overall and it is not the behavior many people want. To stop that you can add `use strict` for tell JS to be in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

```js
'use strict';
var v = "Hi! I'm a strict mode script!"; // this is ok
b = 1 // ReferenceError: b is not defined"
```

Here is the same without `use strict`

```js
var v = "Hi! I'm a NOT strict mode script!"; // this is ok
b = 1 
console.log(b) // returns 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mainFunction() {
array.forEach(function (element, index) {
   for (var key in list) {
     //do something
   }
   let word = "foo"
   //word is defined here.
   //word can call in {array.forEarch(...)}

}
//word is undefined here.

console.log(word)
```

}

Always `let` called in {...}.
For example:  `{ let a; ... {let b;} {let c;} }`